# What is a "pixel valve" in bcm2835 chip

Tags: graphics, gpu, raspberry-pi2, broadcom

In open source driver code of vc4 authored by Eric, there's something called "pixel valve". Apparently it has something to do with display output. But I would really want have more information about what exactly it is? How does it work?

https://github.com/peyo-hd/kernel_rpi/blob/vc4/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2708_common.dtsi

```
pixelvalve@7e807000 {
    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-pixelvalve2";
    reg = <0x7e807000 0x100>;
    interrupts = <2 10>; /* pixelvalve */
};
```

Comment: Post the part of code you mention.

Comment: @LeFlou, It's done:)